# YOLOv8 counting value

Tags: python, yolo, yolov8

I am working on a project to count vehicles on the road without drawing a line using (yolo) when he detects a vehicle he counts it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmzYi.png)

I want to reach this value (3 cars) in yolo?
To perform some operations on it and display it, if someone can help me?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557), and then edit your question.

Comment: It depends a little on your classes but you can see an example of that exact application here: https://github.com/heathhenley/RhodyCarCounter/blob/main/backend/worker/traffic.py#L68  - The docs give the details of the result object that is returned after running predict (https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#working-with-results)

Comment: Have a look at roboflow's excellent repository supervision: https://github.com/roboflow/supervision. It kind of does it magically out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of the same class objects from the results, you need to get the id of this class in `model.names`, and count the appearance of this value in the `results[0].boxes.cls` (takes all detected objects in the image and gets their class_ids).

```
# define the model
model = YOLO('yolov8s.pt')
# run inference on the source image
results = model('image.jpg')
# get the model names list
names = model.names
# get the 'car' class id
car_id = list(names)[list(names.values()).index('car')]
# count 'car' objects in the results
results[0].boxes.cls.tolist().count(car_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can try.

```
# load your model
model = YOLO(model_path)

# save results
res = model.predict(image_file_path)
# save class label names
names = res[0].names    # same as model.names

# store number of objects detected per class label
class_detections_values = []
for k, v in names.items():
    class_detections_values.append(res[0].boxes.cls.tolist().count(k))
# create dictionary of objects detected per class
classes_detected = dict(zip(names.values(), class_detections_values))
```