# Extract and print Yolov8 results

Tags: extract, yolov8

I want to get the detected object names (Persons) and number using Python for input to excel

My code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2

model = YOLO('../Yolo-Weights/yolov8l.pt')
results = model("Images/1.png", show= True)
```

It can detect the object and the output is :

```
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.26  Python-3.10.0 torch-2.0.1+cpu CPU
YOLOv8l summary (fused): 268 layers, 43668288 parameters, 0 gradients, 165.2 GFLOPs

image 1/1 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Object-Detection-101\Chapter 5 - Running Yolo\Images\1.png: 384x640 8 persons, 1 bus, 4 backpacks, 3 handbags, 1 skateboard, 552.9ms
Speed: 1.0ms pre-process, 552.9ms inference, 1.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
```

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886404/yolov8-counting-value/76897980#76897980) and the [official documentation](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#boxes) of how to work with the prediction results.