# Count number of objects detected in each frame

Tags: python, model, yolov8

I have created a custom yolov8 model to detect the toy cars in a video. However, I am unable to count the number of objects detected in each frame.

I tried to use a function to annotate the image

```
def annotate_image(image):

    # perform precidtion
    model = YOLO("runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt")
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = model(image_rgb)

    for i in range(len(results.pandas().xyxy[0].name)):
      name = results.pandas().xyxy[0].name[i]
      startX = int(results.pandas().xyxy[0].xmin[i])
      startY = int(results.pandas().xyxy[0].ymin[i])
      endX = int(results.pandas().xyxy[0].xmax[i])
      endY = int(results.pandas().xyxy[0].ymax[i])
      confidence = results.pandas().xyxy[0].confidence[i]
      label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(name, confidence * 100)
      if confidence > 0.6:
        cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
                  (255,0,0), 2)
        y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
        cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,0), 2)

    return image
```

and used it in this next code

```
video_in_file = DataFolder + '/toycars.mp4'
video_out_file = DataFolder + '/out_custom.mp4'

print("[INFO] accessing video stream...")
v_out = None

v_in = cv2.VideoCapture(video_in_file)
total_frame = int(v_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT ))

for frame_no in tqdm(range(total_frame), desc="Processing Video..."):

  (grabbed, frame) = v_in.read()

  # if the frame was not grabbed then we've reached the end of
  # the video stream so exit the script
  if not grabbed:
      print("[INFO] no frame read from stream - exiting")
      break

  annotated_img = annotate_image(frame)

  # check if the video writer is None
  if v_out is None:
      # initialize our video writer
      fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
      v_out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_out_file, fourcc,
                  int(v_in.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)),
                  (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), True)

  # write the output frame to disk
  v_out.write(annotated_img)

# release the file pointers
print("\n[INFO] cleaning up...")
v_out.release()
v_in.release()
```

but received this error
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'pandas'

Comment: What are you trying to do by calling `results.pandas()`? The `results` in this code is a list of ultralytics.engine.results objects, and as it is stated in the error description, it has no attribute 'pandas'. Check the [official documentation](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#working-with-results) for how to work with the prediction results. Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886404/yolov8-counting-value/76897980#76897980) is a similar question about object counting with yolov8.