# How to count the classes in YOLOv8 on single image

Tags: pytorch, yolo, yolov8

I have custom model of names 0: Pin 1:NOK all I want is after prediction display the count of classes and its confidence at least the count.

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("./runs/detect/train26/weights/best.pt")
def mod():
    results=model.predict('1.JPG', save=True, show=True,show_labels=True,show_conf=True, conf=0.1, save_txt=True)
return results
mod()
```

something like 'class name' : 'count'

Comment: You can try the proposed solutions for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886404/yolov8-counting-value/76897980#76897980